# Call to undefined method CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver when run delete function

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

When I do the delete process there is an error that the method is not found
`CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver`.

`js hide: false console: true babel: false`

```html
function deleteData()
    {   
        // if(empty($this->arr_where)){
        //  die($this->str_tableName." WHERE CONDITION IS EMPTY");
        // }

        if($this->arr_where)
        {
            $this->arr_where = app_trimInput($this->arr_where);
            foreach($this->arr_where as $field => $item_type){
                $quoteField = in_array($field, $this->arr_quoteFields)?false:true;
                $this->_create_whereStatement($field, $item_type, $quoteField);
            }
        }

        $this->db->limit($this->limit);

        $query = $this->db->delete($this->str_tableName);

        if(!in_array($this->str_tableName, $this->arr_unsavedTable)){
            if($this->transactQueries == FALSE){
                app_writeFile($this->db->last_query(), true, true, $this->dirLogQuery);
            }
        }

        $numDeleted = ($this->db->affected_rows() == -1) ? 1 : $this->db->affected_rows();
        // debug
        // log_message('error',' delete affected_rows = '.$numDeleted);
        if($this->db->err_msg() != '')
            log_message('error',' sql_errors = '.$this->db->err_msg());
        return $numDeleted;
    }
```

This is an error I got

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>   Type: Error
>   Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver::err_msg()
>   Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\masteritn\application\models\Globalmodel.php
>   Line Number: 489

Backtrace:

File:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\masteritn\application\controllers\admin\Group_menu.php
Line: 202
Function: deleteData
```

File:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\masteritn\index.php
Line: 314
Function: require_once
```

Comment: please write the error in the post. don't upload error's image. I vote to "closed" the question until you amend it.

Comment: done dude, hopely you can help

Comment: Was the answer helpful? Consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you started out with an outdated tutorial. From what I can see in the [CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver.php](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/master/system/database/drivers/sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php) CI code on GitHub you need to call the `error()` method instead:

```
$this->db->error()
```